# Meaning of 'survey' in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, british-english, archaic-language

Can the word *view* be a good synonym for *survey* in the following context?

> A man does right, as a rule, to have his thoughts more occupied with the interests of his own nation than with those of others, because his actions are more likely to affect his own nation. But in time of war, and in all matters which are of equal concern to other nations and to his own, a man ought to take account of the universal welfare, and not allow his **survey** to be limited by the interest, or supposed interest, of his own group or nation.

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/survey) has defined *survey* as "A general view, examination, or description of someone or something".

Comment: It could be helpful if you [edit] your post and explain which meaning of "view" you intended.

Comment: What is the source? This seems to be a dated usage.

Comment: @user3169, It's written by Bertrand Russell about 100 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on whether that was a standard usage of ***survey*** back then, but it is slightly off-standard now. However, it's close enough to feel familiar.

In that Oxford entry, you will see that all of the noun uses are nouns referring to the act of one of the verb usages. So we can see that the noun could refer to other verb usages as well. Another is "look closely or examine", so we can see that "his survey" can mean "the things he looks at closely or examines".